# simplejson nested object indexing

Tags: python, simplejson

I can't figure out how to perform nested object access using simplejson. I have looked at the examples in the [docs](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.1.1/docs/index.html) and searched but can't find a way of achieving the following functionality:

```
nested = json.loads('{ "foo": {"bar": 1}}')
value = nested['foo.bar']
if(value == 1):
  print('success')
```

This produces the following error:

```
KeyError: 'foo.bar'
```

Is there a way of getting nested objects without having to access one object at a time?

Comment: What is wrong with `nested['foo']['bar']` exactly?

Comment: Thanks Martijn, am new to python and wasn't aware of that syntax for dictionary access. That works fine for my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object returned is a true python dict:

```
>>> type(nested)
<type 'dict'>
```

so really your question is about python dictionaries. So, no, this cannot be done. It would be possible for you to define a custom `JSONDecoder` which could return your own object that implements the semantics you want, however.